# what is a fun beginner project?

Tags: html

I am learning HTML and I have a good book to learn with but my cousin told me that I should pick a fun project to learn how to program but im not sure what I should do.

what is the most fun project to do when you are learning HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a website about something you like or know good. Like, if you are a music fan, do a site about your fave band or some musical instrument. There's no single "fun project".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I think I will make a webpage about the american idol contestants but there are only a few left and the season might be over before my webpage is done :(

Comment: @Att. Good idea :) There is always next year too.

Answer (score 5):

Making your own [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) is a fun place to start.

It will teach you the basics of HTML and the all-important **CSS**.

Comment: Hi I dont understand this page and I dont know what the CSS means.

Comment: CSS = Cascading Style Sheets. Clicking "select a design" will change the way the page looks by swapping the stylesheet, but uses the exact same HTML. This will teach you how stylesheets work.

Answer (score 4):

“Most fun” is hard to say, but a few things which you might find interesting:

- A homepage for yourself
- A Twitter aggregator
- A simple wiki (if you want to learn server-side programming at the same time)
- A recipe list
- A photo album

... and so on ...

And, as others have suggested, it would be a good idea to try and pick up some JavaScript and CSS at the same time… But, if you truly are new to programming, that will get overwhelming very quickly. So it might be a good idea to stick to one thing — say, learning HTML — before you try to learn CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious one is make your own website and/or blog. I enjoyed it when I knew nothing but HTML. Granted, I'd learn some CSS, Javascript, and some Server Side language(such as PHP) as well because HTML on it's own is quite tedious.

Comment: Here are some thoughts by Rob Conery on the topic: http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/be-a-good-jedi-build-your-own-blog/

Comment: @Math You should just make that an answer :)

Comment: I figured this was close enough to your answer that I would just comment, but if I have your official blessing I'll do that ;)

Answer (score 1):

**"Be a Good Jedi: Build Your Own Blog"**
Quoted from Rob Conery's blog: http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/be-a-good-jedi-build-your-own-blog/

> 1) It’s the perfect app for a geek who
>   wants a blog to build – they’re the
>   perfect domain experts
>   2) It’s easy
>   (for the most part) but gets harder
>   and harder the farther in your dive
>   3) It’s ubiquitous. What a perfect
>   interview topic: “I’d love to see how
>   you handled asynchronous pings to
>   Technorati and – oh – do you have a
>   POP feature? Also – did you use
>   MetaWeblog or Wordpress?”
>   4) It’s
>   your calling card. If your blog rocks
>   – likely you do too. If it sucks and
>   it’s slow – well…
>   5) It’s a great
>   way to learn a language. Want to try
>   out ASP.NET MVC? Compare the LOC and
>   features to your Webforms blog – then
>   try Rails…
>   6) Luke did it – and
>   that’s good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're only learning HTML (as opposed to JavaScript, PHP, etc):

1. Pick a topic you're passionate about (your favorite game, movie, book, programming language, hobby, etc)
2. Make a *useful* website about it that will benefit users

Answer (score 0):

My mum started with a family website and created slideshows.  You can gradually move on to your hobbies and share those.

Answer (score 0):

Some fun projects could be:

1. Make a website about something you like or do.
2. Help out a friend and make a website about something he/she likes or does...
3. Help out an small organisation / shop in you neighbourhood (for example a restaurant, a shop, a cafe, a radio station ...) by making their website. Maybe you could get some free beer or food in return :-)